# Como desativar/ativar um evento dblclick JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Bom dia pessoal, seguinte, estou querendo fazer um modo de CRUD rápido, na edição, por exemplo, o ADM dá 2 cliques no campo a ser editado, e o campo se torna editável com 2 botões a direita, um para confirmar e outro para cancelar.

O que eu tenho feito é:

https://jsfiddle.net/gn5pmjzc/

Faça o seguinte exemplo:

Dê 2 cliques em Roberto Afonso, agora dê 2 cliques novamente nele.
Perceba que o texto é apagado.

Minha ideia era, prevenir que este "dlbClick" fosse executar, até o icone de X ou V ser clicado, depois continuava normal..

Como posso fazer?

Obrigado a quem responder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma vez que já estás a adicionar a classe `celulaEmEdicao` quando o `dlbClick` ocorre, então podes simplesmente verificar se a classe lá está e interromper a execução caso esteja.

Assim:

```
$("td").dblclick(function(e) {
    var originalContent = $(this).text();
    if ($(this).hasClass("celulaEmEdicao")) return e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("celulaEmEdicao");
    // etc...
```

Comment: Ahaam, é que temos um pequeno problema.. Os ícones para aceitar a edição ou não, não estão aparecendo. O que ocorre é que:

https://jsfiddle.net/gn5pmjzc/2/

Coloquei a função de quando clicar fora o "EDIT" fecha, agora se eu precisar editar novamente, não trocar o "text" do input. Porque tecnicamente tu mandou ele cancelar isso...

Éra este meu problema :(

Comment: Alguem mais consegue ajuda?

Comment: @Hermus esse icones vêm de onde? Acho que isso é CSS certo? Boostrap talvez?

Comment: É um framework chamado SEMANTIC-UI.... Mas o problema é JS mesmo, depois de "trancar" o evento, ele não habilita pra uso novamente :/

Comment: @Hermus limpei o teu código um pouco https://jsfiddle.net/gn5pmjzc/3/ mas ainda não percebo o que não funciona. Podes experimentar?

Comment: Velho, era basicamente isso, este teu exemplo funcionou perfeitamente, com a exceção de que no console está me mostrando este erro, cada vez que eu dou 2 cliques na td:

Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function -- jquery-3.1.0.js:5110

Comment: Fiz a substituição deste trecho por:

*if ($el.hasClass("celulaEmEdicao")) return event.preventDefault();*


Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelo tempo Sergio. Obrigado